# Can I have a TLS signed certificate without a CA

Tags: tls, certificates

And how can I do that if the answer is Yes?

Comment: There are self-signed certificates if that is what you mean...

Comment: Do you want a certificate that will be accepted by other peoples’s browsers, or only by browsers on machines that you control?

Comment: I guess self signed? Only for internal devices under our control

Comment: For self-signed certificates there are a few available solutions. For example you can either use [openSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) directly or e.g. [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) _etc..._

Comment: openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout file.key -out file.csr

And then

openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in file.csr -signkey file.key -out zc-3-711.pem

Is okay?

Comment: always update your question with details asked in comments so your question contains the full picture

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. But they will be completely pointless if you don't pin their thumbprint to a specific application.

Imagine for a second what you want to use the certificate for: The certificate should provide authenticity, i.e. you want to verify that an entity that claims to be entity X is actually entity X.

Consider the following example: When you get a CA-trusted certificate the CA performs some checks that you are who you claim to be. This allows anybody that wants to authenticate you and trusts the CA to be sure that its actually you. However, when using self-signed certificates there is no preexisting trust and nobody that checks that you are who you claim to be. Thus anybody can claim to be you, thus you gain almost no security whatsoever (except when you specifically pin the thumbprint of your self-signed certificates).

Comment: True

It was more for testing purposes but we are going to build a CA I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

For test purposes you can use a self-signed certificate, but this don't have a sense in production, as the role of a Certificate Authority(CA) is to authenticate the identity of the owner of a website. and if your CA is not valid, so there no way to garanty for the clients that they are really using the right website. when trying to access a website with non valid CA the browser will rise the error `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` and if you decide to continue you have assume the risk and you are not sure if you are using the real website or a man in the middle is serving you.